# Is it possible to set constructor for specific enum?

Tags: java, enums

I know it sounds a bit weird but I will explain what I'm trying to avoid.

I have a bean class that holds some data. This bean class can be constructed from two different sources. I created an enum for each source that I'm passing through the constructor.

Then I need to `switch` on the enum inside the constructor in order to distinguish between the two. I know that I can overload the constructor but the problem is that both sources are providing a `Map<String,Object>`.

I wondered if there is any way to look at the enum value as a final one for the constructor in any way?

```
public PromotedItemRecord(Map<String, Object> record, source recordSource) {
     switch(recordSource)
     ....
}

public enum source
{
    fromDB,
    fromAjax;
}
```

Is it even possible to do so?

Comment: I have no idea what your question is. Why can't you just use the `switch` statement?

Comment: I can , but this is the question :) is there any way to avoid it? ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situations when multiple constructors take parameters of identical type, you should avoid exposing constructors altogether: since constructor name cannot be changed, the user who calls them would have to search through documentation or possibly make guesses at what's going on.

A common approach is to make the constructor private, and provide *factory methods* in place of its overloads:

```
class PromotedItemRecord {
    private PromotedItemRecord(Map<String, Object> record, source recordSource) {
        ... // Do the magic here
    }
    public static recordFromAjax(Map<String, Object> record) {
        return new PromotedItemRecord(record, source.fromAjax);
    }
    public static recordFromDb(Map<String, Object> record) {
        return new PromotedItemRecord(record, source.fromDb);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm... but then i'm ending up in the same situation right? i will still need to switch over the recordSource inside the constructor ..

Comment: @USer22999299 I did this only as an illustration. You could put the common code into a constructor that has a single argument now (i.e. the `record` map) and do the relevant customization of the resultant object in the factory methods by adjusting the map before the call of constructor and/or adjusting the object returned from the constructor.

Comment: yeah, any way i don't think there is a way to avoid the switch over the enum, it must be done in the constructor / factory / any other design..

Comment: @USer22999299 Of course every time you see a switch that you cannot eliminate, there's a good chance that you've missed an opportunity to subclass. Perhaps what you really wanted was a hierarchy of `AbstractPromotedItemRecord` with `AjaxPromotedItemRecord` and `DbPromotedItemRecord` deriving from it.